# How to mouse scroll with Git Bash?

Tags: bash, cmd, command-prompt

Using **Git Bash** or **MinGW Shell**, if I put in a command with much output,
for example `env`, I cannot mouse scroll. A regular old Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) window will do this however.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Enable Quick Edit mode

- Open Properties: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>P</kbd> (for properties)
- Under *Options* tab > *Edit Options* > Check **Quick Edit** > Hit *OK*

Now you will be able to scroll with mouse.

Comment: To *permanently* enable Quick Edit, open Properties from the Git Bash program shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of the git bash you don't have any property such as **Quick Edit** but then too your scroll might not work as it was my case..

- press `alt + space` then click `options` and go to  `window` then
- Simply change your scrollbar location from right to left or vice versa then it will work, at least worked for me.